# Is there something like style group?

Tags: android, styles, themes

I have two group of views which should use different styles, just call them leftStyles and rightStyles.

the two group of views have the same layout.xml , I want to programly change the "styleGroup" of the container to change all it's children's style, just like a theme.
Did it exist a "view group level" theme that can be apply to a Layout?

The two groups are in the same page so I can not distinct them with theme.

Is there some way that I can set a group of styles at a ViewGroup, so the styles can be used by it's children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps you.This is style where you can declare your group style, child style , single style ... just like this

```
<style name="Widget.Group" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">46dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">-1dp</item> <!-- Ensures we don't get a 2 dp top stroke -->
        <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Top">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_top</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Bottom">

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_bottom</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Group.Single" parent="Widget.Group.Top">
        <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_input_group_single</item>-->
    </style>
```

and your layout file you cad use this style like this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eee">

    <!-- Input Group -->
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Top" />
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group" />
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Bottom" />

    <!-- Single item -->
    <EditText style="@style/Widget.Group.Single" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for more details [click](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/02/05/taking-advantage-of-android-styles/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I have a layout.xml for my widget group, I want to programly change the "styleGroup" of the container to change all it's children's style, just like a theme.(I am not sure this is realizable)  In your demo code, we should change every child's style.